# How to fix Readiness Check Errors of Magento 2 Extension Installation

Tags: php, magento2

I just want to ask how to fix the Component Dependencies and PHP Extension Check Errors on the Readiness Check of Extension Installation. I am using Magento 2 and PHP 7.0 .26

[see component dependencies' error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uKOL.png)

[see php extension's error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK9xC.png)

Comment: at least you have to install the php xsl module... the retry and see if the other exception remains

Comment: I have already enabled xsl extension from the cpanel of my hosting provider Godaddy. But it still doesn't work...